# Cant understand why my generic code is not working

Tags: java, generics, generic-type-argument

Below is a simple implementation of a linked list. I have just added the relevant code.
First, I add some values to the list, 10,990 and 10000. When I am searching for the same values, I get true for key = 10, but false for key = 990 and key = 10000, though it should be true. Also, if I change the second value from 990 to 99 and search for key = 99, this time I am getting a true.

I am not sure about using generic type. I guess I am doing something wrong there. Because if I replace generic type with int, I get the correct behavior. Please suggest.

```
    public class LinkedListTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedList<Integer> num = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            num.add(10);            
            num.add(990);
            num.add(10000);
            int key = 10; 
            System.out.println("Key " + key + " found ?" + num.findValue(key));
            key = 990; //also checked for Integer key = 990
            System.out.println("Key " + key + " found ?" + num.findValue(key));
            key = 10000;
            System.out.println("Key " + key + " found ?" + num.findValue(key));
        }
    }

    class LinkedList<T>{
        private Node<T> first;
        private class Node<T>{
           private T data;
           private Node<T> next;

           public Node(T data){
               this.data = data;
               this.next = next;
           }
       }

    public void add(T data){
        Node<T> nn = new Node<T>(data);
        nn.next = first;
        first = nn;
    }

    public boolean findValue(T key){
        Node current = first;
        while(current != null){
            if(current.data == key)
                return true;
            else
                current = current.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: do not compare objects with `==` that is general rule of thumb and issue in your code

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you adding to the front of your linked list? You can certainly add elements however you like, but adding to the end seems like a more common pattern.

Comment: does it really deserve a downvote....considering that not using equals is a fundamental flaw,however a person may not know that Integer class caches Object values from -128 to 127(1 byte)

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: ha ha...negative votes for asking questions!!...thanks to the person who gave that...and many thanks to others who helped me out.

Comment: @drum community users should decide if the question deserves up or down votes. There's no specific rule to say that a question cannot be downvoted.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar the only reason to up or downvote a question/answer is by user opinion. There's no exact rule that states a question *deserves a downvote*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `==` operator compares two object references to see if they refer to the same object.  With `Integer` values, the JVM will cache `Integer`s from `-128` through `127`.

From the [`Integer.valueOf` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-):

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

When `10` and `99` are boxed, they result in the same `Integer` object (respectively) when another `10` and `99` are boxed.  However, boxing non-cached `Integer` objects such as `990` and `10000` will result in different `Integer` objects each time.

Replace `==` with the `equals` method, to compare the key contents, not the key references.

```
if(current.data != null && current.data.equals(key))
```

Comment: int caching...good callout.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using .equals() instead of == when checking if you've found the value you're looking for:

```
public boolean findValue(T key){
    Node current = first;
    while(current != null){
        if(current.data != null && current.data.equals(key))
            return true;
        else
            current = current.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When you declare your LinkedList as a list of Integers, your primitive int is wrapped in an Integer object before it is stored in the node. Thus == doesn't always work because you're not comparing two primitives.

Comment: thank you Cameron..the code works fine with the change u suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using == instead of equals.
It works for int which is a primitive type, but for Integer (object) == returns true only if the two members are the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be "generic" you should use equals method instead of == operator.